# How does the compiler know the type of variables of a function pointer

Tags: c, function-pointers

I am learning C by [building my own Lisp](http://buildyourownlisp.com/chapter11_variables) and I'm having troubles figuring out, why does the compiler not complain if my function pointer `builtin_def` is not declared?, And how does the compiler know the type of the variables that are passing as parameters?

```
// function pointer
typedef lval*(*lbuiltin)(lenv*, lval*);

lval* builtin_def(lenv* e, lval* a){
    return lval_sexpr(); 
}

void lenv_add_builtins(lenv* e){
    lenv_add_builtin(e, "def", builtin_def); // builtin_def not declared
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    lenv* e = lenv_new(); // constructor
    lenv_add_builtins(e)
    return 0;
}
```

Notice that I don't have a declaration of `builtin_def` like this:

```
lenv*(*builtin_def)(lenv*, lval*);
```

Comment: You declare `builtin_def` three lines above. (And you also define it at the same time.)

Comment: Yes, but I thought that is just a function and not a function pointer

Comment: The bare name of a function *is* a function pointer. `builtin_def` is a pointer to the function whereas `builtin_def(e, a)` ia a function call.

Comment: A function normally decays into a function pointer.

Comment: ok, I get it. So when is necessary to declare the function pointer `lenv*(*builtin_def)(lenv*, lval*);`? and when is better just to call the bare name of a function?

Comment: You would use your typedef to declare a variable of that function-pointer type. Most often found in function parameters (e.g. qsort). But you could also have a piece of code that needs to decide which function to call based on some condition, and use that type of variable for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring `builtin_def` a few lines above. And you get an automatic conversion to function pointer: (C99 §6.3.2.1)

> A *function designator* is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the
>   operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, a
>   function designator with type ‘‘function returning type’’ is converted to an expression that
>   has type **‘‘pointer to function returning type’’**.

So that all works fine.